# How to control the volume of an iPhone programmatically in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, controls, volume

It seems currently not being possible to control the volume of for example a playing movie from the iPhone screen. I always have to use the physical buttons.

I tried to control the volume of a movie playing on the iPhone with a slider, but there was no slider visible